# Unexpressive WebDriver errors in Codeception

Tags: laravel, selenium, phantomjs, codeception

I'm just migrating to Codeception, for my acceptance tests.

Here is my acceptance.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
      - WebDriver
      - \Helper\Acceptance
      - Db

  config:
    WebDriver:
        url: 'http://laravel.dev'
        browser: 'phantomjs'
    Db:
        dsn: 'mysql:host=laravel.dev;dbname=test'
        user: 'homestead'
        password: 'secret'
```

Thing is when I use Webdriver, and I have an error in my tests, I get this kind of error, that doesn't help much:

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException]                                                                                                                                                      
JSON decoding of remote response failed.                                                                                                                                                               
Error code: 4                                                                                                                                                                                          
The response: 'Invalid Command Method - Request => {"headers": {"Accept":"application/json","Content-Length":"0","Content- Type":"application/json;charset=UTF- 8","Host":"127.0.0.1:4444"},"httpVersion  
 ":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/log/types","urlParsed": {"anchor":"","query":"","file":"types","directory":"/log/","path":"/log/t ypes","relative":"/log/types","port":"","host":"","password":"","user"  
     :"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/log/types","que ryKey":{},"chunks":["log","types"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/44be5ec0- 1de2-11e6-ac4e-297abcf5a22b/log/types"}'
```

When I change WebDriver for Laravel5, ( but Documentation say not to use it for acceptance tests.) my errors are not explicits, like that:

```
1) AuthTestCept (tests/acceptance/AuthTestCept.php)

Step  I click "#choose-account-0"
Fail  Link or Button by name or CSS or XPath element with '#choose-account-0' was not found.

Scenario Steps:

3. $I->click("#choose-account-0") at tests/acceptance/AuthTestCept.php:33
2. $I->click("#google") at tests/acceptance/AuthTestCept.php:32
```

So, I'm a bit annoyed about that... Any way to have clean errors with WebDriver???